# Fixed component in TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I made my own Header component in TabNavigator (react-navigation).
When I'm swiping between tabs, every component is swiping as well.
Is it possible to make fixed Header during swiping between different tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add headerMode :float in navigation options of TabNavigator, as mentioned in this link [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Navigator in a root view then provide header inside the view

Pseudo code wll look like

```
<View>
<Header/>
<TabNavigator/>
</View>
```

Header will remain constant while the tab navigator works as indented